# Como usar o bloco if com tipos de variáveis em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tipagem, condição

Estou criando um programa em Python e preciso que necessariamente os dados do campo ID sejam números inteiros. Basicamente eu quero entrar no bloco `if` dependendo do tipo da variável que eu obter. Exemplo:

```
ID = "joão"

# Se ID não for string, deverá ser executado o código abaixo:
print("ID não é uma string")
```

**Código para obter os dados:**

```
from tkinter import *

def cria_entradas():
    # Código para criar os objetos de Entry ...

def pega_dados():

    nome = nome_entry.get()
    id  = id_entry.get()
    tipo = tipo_entry.get()
    localizacao = localizacao_entry.get()
```

Comment: Gente no que eu errei na formulação? Aqui não é pra perguntar isso não?

Comment: Não da para entender o que você quer.

Comment: Ah certo vou ajeitar, obrigado Danilo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para fazer essa verificação, você pode usar a função [type](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#type) passando como argumento a sua variável `ID`. O que essa função faz é simplesmente retornar a classe a que o objeto pertence. Logo você pode verificar se ele é ou não um número inteiro dessa forma:

```
if type(ID) == int:
    print("É um número inteiro.")
else:
    print("O valor de ID é um",type(ID))
```

O problema é que como você está usando o método `get` dos objetos de Entry, você obterá sempre uma string independentemente se a entrada é um número ou não.

Então utilize o método de string `isnumeric` para saber se ele é um número ou não. Exemplo:

```
if ID.isnumeric():
    print("É um número inteiro.")
else:
    print("Não é um número inteiro.")
```

É importante avisar que este método é bem abrangente e existem vários caracteres definidos pelo *Unicode* que são considerados números para o método `isnumeric`.
Clique [aqui](https://ideone.com/K4R1Fd) para ver a lista dos caracteres que o método retorna `True`.

---

**Usando um bloco try-except:**

Você também pode verificar se o valor obtido é um número ou não, fazendo uma conversão do valor para `int()` dentro de um bloco *try - except*.

Caso o valor seja convertido corretamente, significa que ele é numérico e o programa prosseguirá no bloco `try`. Se não for possível convertê-lo, o `ValueError` gerado fará o programa entrar no bloco `except`. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
try:
    ID = int(ID)
    print("ID é um número inteiro.")

except:
    print("ID não é um número inteiro.")
```

---

**Usando isinstance e issubclass:**

Fugindo agora um pouquinho da questão de verificar se o dado é numérico ou não, podemos verificar tipos de objetos de uma forma melhor, que é utilizando as funções [isinstance](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_isinstance.asp) e [issubclass](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_issubclass.asp).

O que a função `isinstance` faz é retornar True ou False verificando se um objeto é uma instância de uma classe X.

```
isinstance( "Olá mundo!", str )  # True
isinstance( 2.345, int)          # False
```

Já a função `issubclass` retorna True ou False verificando se uma classe Y é filha de uma classe X, ou seja, verificamos se a classe Y é *sub-classe* de X.

```
class ClasseX: pass
class ClasseY ( ClasseX ): pass

issubclass( ClasseY, ClasseX )  # True
issubclass( ClasseY, object )   # True
issubclass( int, object )       # True
issubclass( str, float)         # False
```

**Observação:** Diferentemente das funções `type` e `isinstance`, não deve ser passado como parâmetro para a função `issubclass`um objeto e sim uma classe. Logo se quissemos verificar se um objeto pertence a uma classe filha de X, devemos primeiro obter sua classe, exemplo:

```
classe = type(objeto)
print( issubclass( classe, ClasseX ) )
```

Comment: Isso mesmo cara, valeu.

Comment: Em Python, deve-se evitar a verificação de tipo com `type(obj) == classe` - uma vez que essa validação quebra com subclasses e classes virtuais. O correto é verificar com a chamada `isinstance`:  `if isinstance(ID, int): `  no caso do seu primeiro exemplo.

Comment: Obrigado pela sua observação @jsbueno, eu realmente tinha me esquecido dessa função. Eu já adicionei ela na resposta e acrescentei também o uso da função `issubclass` para ficar mais completa a resposta.