# Como saber o tipo primitivo de uma variavel no python

Tags: python, python-3.x

(Sou inciante)

Eu tenho o seguinte dicionário:

```
'''
d = {'nome': ' ', 'Idade': 0, 'carteira de trabalho': 0,
 'ano de contrato': 0, 'salário': 0.0}
'''
```

Esta é a versão inicial dele, e tenho que inserir novos valores a medida que o usuario os digita. Pensei em usar um loop for para fazer isso.

```
'''
for k in d.keys():
    d[k] = input(f'{k}: ')
'''
```

O problema é: Alguns valores no dicionário são strings, enquanto outros são ints. Pensei em resolver o problema utilizando um if, mas para isso vou precisar saber qual é o tipo primitivo do valor k.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Como usar if com tipos de variaveis em python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/406909/como-usar-if-com-tipos-de-variaveis-em-python) (tradução do moderador: "isso responderia sua pergunta? [Como usar if com tipos de variaveis em python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/406909/como-usar-if-com-tipos-de-variaveis-em-python)")

Answer (score 1):

Samuel,

Para retornar o tipo da variável, você pode utilizar a função `type` do Python, ela retorna qual o tipo da variável.

Existe também a função `isinstance`, que ao contrário de retornar um tipo, você envia o tipo e a variável e ela retorna um boolean conforme a variável for do tipo que você informou.

---

Veja um exemplo:

```
inteiro = 0
string = "string"

print(type(inteiro))
print(type(string))

if type(inteiro) == int:
  print("É um inteiro")

if type(string) == str:
  print("É uma string")

print("É uma string?", isinstance(string, str))
print("É um inteiro?", isinstance(inteiro, int))
```

> Veja online: https://repl.it/repls/GargantuanBrokenNature

---

> Referência:
>
> https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type
>
> https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance