# O programa não está reconhecendo número inteiro como tal

Tags: python, python-3.x, validação, tipagem

```
a = int (input ("insira um número :"))

if a != int :  
    print ("isto não é um numero inteiro") 

else :
   print ("seu número foi :"+ str(a))
```

Estou tentando fazer um programa em que o usuário coloque um valor e o programa diga qual foi o valor que ele inseriu, mas se inserisse uma letra, desse tela de erro.

Acontece que quando ele insere um número o programa não reconhece como tal.

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como usar o bloco if com tipos de variáveis em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/406909/como-usar-o-bloco-if-com-tipos-de-vari%c3%a1veis-em-python)

Comment: passe a variavel no type() para poder condicionar com seu tipo: type(var) != int

Comment: Não faz sentido testar o tipo do retorno da função `int()` porque essa função **SEMPRE** retorna um objeto do tipo `int`! O que você quer é capturar a exceção que ocorre quando a função `int()` tenta converter um texto inválido; Veja a resposta abaixo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python, as suas funções padrões, detecta conversões impossíveis através de um mecanismo de exceção, então tem que capturar a exceção para identificar que houve erro, assim:

```
try:
    a = int(input("insira um número: "))
    print ("seu número foi: " + str(a))
except ValueError:
    print ("isto não é um numero inteiro")
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/JP1Uc2). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/ValueErrorpy). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Typing/ValueError.py).