# Como fazer o programa reconhecer automaticamente entrada como int ou str?

Tags: python

Minha dúvida é simples: Eu quero criar um código que o usuário digite qualquer coisa e o programa retorne algumas informações sobre o que ele digitou. (tipo, caracteres, etc.). É um programa muito simples, porém a ideia é entender como posso fazer para o input deixar de ser sempre str e ser o que o usuário digitou. Exemplo: Se ele digitou um número, eu quero que seja convertido num int e se foi texto, que fique como str.

```
# NÃO CONSEGUI RESOLVER

    a=input('Digite qualquer coisa: ')
    print(type(a))
    print('Possui',len(a),'caracteres')
    # Se o caractere digitado for uma int, eu quero que caia no if. Não sei como fazer isso pq no input, por padrão sempre é str
    if type(a)==int:
        if a%2==0:
            print("Par")
        else:
            print("Ímpar")
```

Se eu definir no início do código o input como int, a função len() não funciona.
Como posso corrigir isso tb?

Comment: O conceito do código é estranho e talvez errado, e o conceito de tipo de dado e qual é o conteúdo ser a mesma coisa está errado. Mas para reconhecer se um dado é um número válido tem o código na pergunta na respondida, e aí pode fazer o que deseja. E tem algumas alternativas.

Comment: Isso responde a sua pergunta ? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/406912/157404